# Errors when trying to save command line output to a file

Tags: python, linux, unicode, command-line, pipe

I was running a python tool and trying to save its output to a file. If I don't save the output to a file, the tool runs perfectly fine. But when I try to save the output to the file, it throws following error and interrupt the program:

```
  File "./androdiff.py", line 118, in <module>
main(options, arguments)
  File "./androdiff.py", line 94, in main
ddm.show()
  File "./elsim/elsim/elsim_dalvik.py", line 772, in show
self.eld.show()
  File "./elsim/elsim/elsim.py", line 435, in show
i.show()
  File "./elsim/elsim/elsim_dalvik.py", line 688, in show
  print hex(self.bb.bb.start + self.offset), self.pos_instruction, self.ins.get_name(), self.ins.show_buff( self.bb.bb.start + self.offset )
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0111' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried `command |less` , `command > output` and `command | tee output`, all of them will throw such error.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: When you "save to file" are you redirecting `stdout`? Like so `python app.py > file` ?

Comment: Yes. That's what I use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to specify the encoding of your string before you print it:

```
print unicode(hex(self.bb.bb.start + self.offset)).encode('utf-8')
print unicode(self.pos_instruction, self.ins.get_name()).encode('utf-8')
print unicode(self.ins.show_buff( self.bb.bb.start + self.offset )).encode('utf-8')
```

The reason this works is because python automatically encodes your string correctly (in your case utf-8) when printing to the terminal (it detects that the terminal uses utf-8).

When you are redirecting your output to a file instead, Python has no information about what encoding it should use and it defaults to ascii instead (which is causing your error).

As a general rule of thumb, make sure you always encode your string before printing to make `print` work in all environments.

The best method may be to define your own print method for this:

```
def myprint(unicodestr): 
    print unicodestr.encode('utf-8')
```

If you want to avoid the above and make printing with utf-8 encoding the default you can do

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout=codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(sys.stdout)
```

Beware of this approach! Some third-party libraries may depend on the default encoding being  ascii and break. Note that this whole mess has been resolved in Python 3 (which defaults to UTF-8 encoding)

Comment: Thanks! Martin. Can I change the defaults from ascii to utf-8 instead of change every invocations of `print`? There are tons of places using `print` in the tool, and I don't bother to refactor every one of them.

Comment: you shouldn't hardcode user's terminal character encoding in your script. You could use [`PYTHONIOENCODING` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24870668/4279).

Answer (score 3):

Set `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable explicitly if stdout character encoding can't be determined automatically e.g., when the output is redirected to a file:

```
$ PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 python app.py > file
```

Don't hardcode the character encoding in your scripts if the output may go to a terminal; print Unicode strings instead and let users to configure their environment.

Comment: This is what I needed - terminal took the output OK, and for small outputs I could copy-paste it correctly. The variable name is not very handy, but it could save the day. I need to check, if this works with `os.environ`. OK - it does.